# Is there a way to check if 2 lines are intersecting, and what is the intersection point?

Tags: java, math, geometry, line

With the help of @Alex , I'v managed to create this following code:

```
  // Returns true if the lines intersect, false otherwise
    public boolean isIntersecting(Line other) {
        if (equals(other)){
            return false;
        }
        double x11 = this.start.getX();
        double y11 = this.start.getY();
        double x12 = this.end.getX();
        double y12 = this.end.getY();

        double x21 = other.start.getX();
        double y21 = other.start.getY();
        double x22 = other.end.getX();
        double y22 = other.end.getY();

        // special handling may be needed when x11 == x12
        double m1 = (y12 - y11) / (x12 - x11);
        double b1 = (x11 * y12 - x12 * y11) / (x12 - x11);

        // special handling may be needed when x21 == x22
        double m2 = (y22 - y21) / (x22 - x21);
        double b2 = (x21 * y22 - x22 * y21) / (x22 - x21);

        if ((long) m1 == (long) m2) {
           if (this.start == other.start)
               return true;
           if (other.start == other.end)
               return true;
            if (other.start == this.end)
                return true;
            if (other.start == this.start)
                return true;
           return false;
        }
        double x = (b2 - b1)/(m1 - m2);
        double y = m1 * x + b1;  // or m2 * x + b2
        if (x>x11 && x<x12 && y<y11 && y>y12 && x>x21 && x<x22 && y<y21 && y>y22) {
            Point.intersection = new Point(x, y);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // Returns the intersection point if the lines intersect,
    // and null otherwise.
    public Point intersectionWith(Line other) {
        if (isIntersecting(other)) {
            return Point.intersection;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is, that I don't really know whether the lines have only one intersection or more. I don't know which more things I have to do and which conditions to check to verify they have only ONE intersection.

I have to say that the lines don't have to be infinite. Which means one line can start where the second one ends, and they will have also the same slope ("m") and also only one intersection.

Also, I want to learn how to send the intersection point correctly because I think I did it wrong and sent it wrongly to the second function.

Comment: What is the purpose of x1, x2, y1 and y2 if you already have a start and end point?

Comment: They always intersect, unless they're parallel. You can calculate the intersection of eg the x that satisfies. m1*x + b1 = m2*x + b2, then you check if that x value is between your x1 and x2 values.

Comment: Should help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-point-of-intersection-of-two-lines/

Comment: @bramhaag I don't have the start and end point, i'm initializing them in the rest of the code(which I did not show here) while using this.start = new Point(x1, y1)
this.end = new Point(x2, y2)

Comment: Please don't compare objects with `==` operator (e.g. in `if (this.start == other.start)` etc.), you need to override and use `equals`

Comment: If you want to make sure that intersection point is applied to _segments_ you have to check if x gets between x11 and x12 like this: `if x>Math.min(x11, x12) && x<Math.max(x11, x12)`  because it is not quaranteed that `x11 < x12` - this needs to be applied to all comparisons.

Comment: Why you set Point.intersection?  Is it some static field in `Point` class that will be changed each time you run `isIntersecting` method for other lines?  It may work somehow in your single-threaded app, but generally is not recommended.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Hi man, thanks for your help. Thanks for  the advice about the "equals". And yes, I want to make sure that the intersection point is on the segment so I check if x gets between the x's of the start and end points of each line. (right?) (and same about "y"). Why can I just compare it like I did with "x11<x && x<x12"? And I set Point.intersection because I want my first function to return True/False on if there is an intersection, and the second function will return the intersection point / null (if there is no point). So I thought about saving it into static field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method finds intersection of two straight lines (all cases) and returns an intersection point.

If the input lines are parallel or coincide, `null` Point is returned.

```
    public static Point findIntersection(Line line1, Line line2) {
        double x11 = line1.getX1();
        double y11 = line1.getY1();
        double x12 = line1.getX2();
        double y12 = line1.getY2(); 

        double x21 = line2.getX1();
        double y21 = line2.getY1();
        double x22 = line2.getX2();
        double y22 = line2.getY2();

        if (x11 == x12 && x21 == x22) {  // both lines are constant x
            if (x11 == x21) {
                System.out.println("Lines coincide");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Lines are parallel to each other and axis 0Y");
            }
            // no intersection point
            return null;

        } else if (x11 == x12 || x21 == x22) { // either line is constant x
            double x;
            double m;
            double b;
            if (x11 == x12) { // first line is constant x, second is sloped
                x = x11;
                m = (y22 - y21) / (x22 - x21);
                b = (x22 * y21 - x21 * y22) / (x22 - x21);
            } else { // second line is constant x, first is sloped
                x = x21;
                m = (y12 - y11) / (x12 - x11);
                b = (x12 * y11 - x11 * y12) / (x12 - x11);
            }
            double y = m * x + b;

            System.out.printf("Lines intersect in (%.2f, %.2f)%n", x, y);

            return new Point(x, y);

        } else { // both lines are sloped
            double m1 = (y12 - y11) / (x12 - x11);
            double b1 = (x12 * y11 - x11 * y12) / (x12 - x11);

            double m2 = (y22 - y21) / (x22 - x21);
            double b2 = (x22 * y21 - x21 * y22) / (x22 - x21);

            if (m1 == m2) {
                if (b1 == b2) {
                    System.out.println("Sloped lines coincide");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Lines are parallel with slope " + m1);
                }
                // no intersection point
                return null;
            }
            // calculating intersection coordinates
            double x = (b2 - b1)/(m1 - m2);
            double y = m1 * x + b1;  // or m2 * x + b2

            System.out.printf("Lines intersect in (%.2f, %.2f)%n", x, y);

            return new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also added the option of what happens when line1 and line2 are merging and basically are the same line.

Comment: Hey @Alex, is there any way to "split" this into 2 different  functions? the first one will return true or false based on if it's the 2 lines are intersecting, and the second one will find the intersection point? I mean I can just do the same math in 2 different functions, but it's inefficient. I'm trying to find a way to find the intersection point without the need to get the "m" and do the same math as you did in the first function. What do you think? Because mathematically speaking, we don't need to find the "m" (sorry forgot the word) in order to find the intersection point..

Comment: your code only check whether the lines are parallel or not. But it's not enough to show that they have an intersection point. We got to check if the intersection point in on both of the lines, don't you think?

Comment: What do you mean by _check if the intersection point in on both of the lines_?  Two lines on Euclidean plane either intersect in one point, or are parallel.

Comment: We were told that we can't expect the lines to be infinite, so I can't just decide that they are either intersect or are parallel only by comparing their slope "m".  and I meant by the sentence you quoted that we can find the intersection point and then check if it's X & Y values are on both lines to 100% know it's the intersection point.

Comment: I mean he told us that yes, in theory, the lines will have an intersection if they are not parallel. But he wants them to "really" cut each other and not their function in theory. So he told us that comparing the slopes is not enough to deicde. He told us "for example, what will happen if one line will finish in the exact point that line2 will start". and yes, I saw your comments about "special handling" for the exact cases, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: and of course we have another options like "y=5" or "x=3". They do intersect but have no slope.

Comment: Lines are infinite by [definition](https://www.mathstips.com/point-ray-line-and-line-segment/).  What you described as _finite line_ is called line segments. My method does exactly what it's intended to - it finds intersection point for infinite lines and i updated it to handle all the cases.

Comment: Hey @Alex thanks alot. Does your new method covers all possible cases because there are alot of cases that I implanted into your old code, for eg: If slopes are the same - check whether the start point of line1 is the end point of line2, and cases like that that can still find an intersection even though the slopes are even.

Comment: I mean at your code: "if ((long) m1 == (long) m2) {...", you just checked if the slopes are even. But I think I do have to add my "if (this.start == other.start)" cases to this, don't you think? (and of course change it to equals because I won't compare objects with "=="). Because as I told you, we are talking here  about segments, which means 2 lines can have the same slope and still intersect, so I have to check it. Right? And also I think I need to add to your code a check of if the x & y values of the intersection point are on the segments.

Comment: I fixed that issue with the slopes -  it was indeed incorrect.  I will highly appreciate if you accept my answer because it provides proper solution to your initial request _Is there a way to check if 2 **lines** are intersecting, and what is the intersection point?_  If you have more questions about details of finding intersection point or subsegment for _segments_, please create another question.  Thanks!